# Est-il incorrect d'écrire « Veuille trouver le document » ?

Tags: usage, correspondance, tutoiement

Lors d'un courriel, il est très commun d'écrire

> Veuillez trouver ci-joint le document demandé.

Si l'on tutoie le destinataire, l'on emploiera plutôt quelque chose comme

> Tu trouveras ci-joint le document demandé.

**Question** : Je n'ai jamais lu ni entendu la formule

> Veuille trouver ci-joint le document demandé.

mais est-elle pour autant incorrecte ? Je ne vois pas d'argument qui aille dans ce sens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grammaticalement, si l'on suit les règles de construction de l'impératif,  cette formulation est correcte, c'est un emploi bien formé de l'impératif à la deuxième personne du singulier. Cependant cet emploi du verbe *vouloir* est généralement la marque d'une politesse formelle et il se marie par conséquent extrêmement mal avec le tutoiement.

Comment: S'il est vrai que cela se marie mal, pour l'usage actuel, je me rappelle entendre dans un contexte très (trop) formel "Puissiez-vous" + infinitif. C'est un peu le même genre, non ?

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que bien que peut-être grammaticalement correcte, la formulation "veuillez trouver" est la seule correcte puisque le tutoiement n'as pas sa place dans une structure aussi formelle.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord. Si cela est grammaticalement correcte, alors ça l'est entièrement !
Il ne faut juste pas l'utiliser pour envoyer son curriculum vitae ou pour transmettre un mail à son banquier, c'est tout. Moi j'utilise cette forme avec des amis, et je n'ai absolument pas l'impression de faire une faute, au contraire. Cordia

Answer (score 1):

La conjugaison du verbe *vouloir* à l'impératif présent :

> veux / veuille
>   voulons
>   voulez / veuillez

indique qu'il est tout-à-fait correct de dire :

> Veuille trouver ci-joint le document demandé.

Bien que cela me semble un peu étrange à l'oreille.

Answer (score 1):

On ne peut pas utiliser "veuille", il n'est d'usage que dans les adresses au destin ou aux divinités (à la troisième personne qui est identique).
Quand tu écris "veuille" à quelqu'un, son premier réflexe sera de chercher à quelle divinité tu t'adresses (bon ce sera le deuxième réflexe, le premier étant de chercher de quelle tragédie de Racine c'est extrait).
Par ailleurs, de manière formelle, on ne tutoie pas - la mode copiée de la manière anglo-saxonne crée une proximité qui exclut en français tout formalisme langagier autre que le respect de la politesse et un vocabulaire courant. De même tu ne termineras pas ton courrier par "veuille agréer, je te prie, l'expression de mes sentiments distingués".

Answer (score 0):

Dans ce cas la bonne formule est :

> je te prie de trouver ci-joint le document demandé

Answer (score -1):

Dans les rapports professionnels, je trouve que la formulation *« Veuille ... »* allie merveilleusement bien la proximité à la formalité