# Impératif de "vouloir"

Tags: histoire, conjugaison, impératif

J'ai trouvé deux formes différentes pour l'impératif de vouloir en cherchant sur internet. Certains sites proposent "veux, voulons, voulez" en plus de "veuille, veuillons, veuillez" (et parfois il n'y a pas de "veuillons" mais uniquement "voulons"). Pour ma part, j'ai souvent rencontré "veuillez" mais pas les autres formes. Quelqu'un saurait-il me dire comment ces deux formes ont évolué/cohabité au cours du temps ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'usage de l'impératif de vouloir a toujours été rare car lorsqu'il s'applique à un verbe à l'infinitif, c'est ce dernier verbe seul à l'impératif qui est plutôt utilisé.

> « Veux te battre ! » → Bats toi !

La première forme (veux/voulons/voulez), calquée sur l'indicatif, ne se rencontre guère que dans des tournures négatives (mais « en vouloir » a un sens bien différent de « vouloir ») :

> Ne lui en veux pas !
>
> Ne lui en voulons pas !
>
> Ne leur en voulez pas !

La deuxième forme, plus ancienne, calquée sur le subjonctif, est un impératif atténué essentiellement utilisé aujourd'hui dans des formules de courtoisie.

Seule la deuxième personne du pluriel se rencontre car [le tutoiement est peu compatible avec une formule de politesse](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13682/est-il-incorrect-d%C3%A9crire-veuille-trouver-le-document) :

> Mais veuille sauver mes jours…
>
> Veuillez signer ici !

Comment: merci, je n'avais pas pensé à "ne lui en voulez pas". Est-ce que "veuille sauver mes jours..." est tiré d'un texte ancien ?

Comment: Oui ;-) L'iliade d'Homère, ou plutôt de sa traduction bien sûr.

Comment: Un peu en marge de la question, mais intéressant selon moi: «Veux-tu bien!», qui possède une structure interrogative appliquée à l'indicatif présent, mais qui s'utilise en réalité ni plus ni moins comme un ordre à cesser qqch. C'est très utilisé au Québec. L'est-ce aussi en France?

Comment: @Feelew Pas que je sache, je ne me souviens pas avoir entendu cette expression.

Answer (score 0):

« Veux-tu bien ! » fleure sa bourgeoisie d'entre-deux-guerres, peut-être l'entendrait-on encore de personnes âgées ?

J'ai déjà entendu : « Veuille bien […] », impératif dont la valeur jussive est volontairement atténuée par politesse et/ou affection.

Veuillez me pardonnez cette réponse non encyclopédique ?

Comment: Ceci aurait probablement dû être proposé en commentaire sous la réponse de jlliagre. «Veux-tu bien!» n’a que peu à voir avec la question, et c’était une interrogation lancée comme ça par curiosité, en commentaires...